# Deploying MEAN stack, Mongo no output result

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack

I have a MEAN project. I am deploying this to Heroku, but unable to get Mongo data. I build the angular app in backend folder.

File Path:

```
--ProjectName
 |-frontend (angular app)
 |-backend (node.js server)
  |-public (Folder where angular project gets built)
```

Used this for Heroku deployment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#deploy-the-app

I have node server as:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose');

const Confession = require('./database/confession');
const Art = require('./database/art');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3100;

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
});

.....

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('Server running on port 3100'));
```

Added mongoDB Atlas to server, added username, password and dbname:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.5zol8.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => console.log('Database connected'))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

module.exports = mongoose;
```

This deploys angular frontend app but unable to fetch MongoDB Atlas data. I get error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders, 
  status: 404, 
  statusText: "Not Found", 
  url: "http://localhost:3100/confessions", 
  ok: false, 
  …
}
```

Here's my web service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebService {
  readonly ROOT_URL;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get(uri: String) {
    return this.http.get(`${uri}`);
  }
}
```

How do I solve this? What is going wrong?

Comment: once you deployed your code in to a server, localhost urls are no longer working. Try to replace them by necessary domain urls. In your case, I hope 'http://localhost:4200/' should be replaced by your heroku app url. For deeper dive please provide your angular code above.

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be localhost:3100 as I am running the app with nodemon. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure this app is working correctly on local enviornment?

Comment: Try my answer mentioned below and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Import `bodyParser`package to your express app and set **CORS** policy as below.
This may be helpful.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  next();
});
```

Comment: Nope didn't work. Do you need anymore information? I tried to give everything I can.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: ```app.get("/sendfile", function(req,res){     
    app.set('view engine', 'html');     
    res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + 'public/index.html'); 
});``` This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/sendfile", function(req,res){          
   app.set('view engine', 'html');          
   res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + 'public/index.html');  
});
```

This worked for me